# AWS Glue Python shell jobs: No space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm running a Glue job with the following configurations
Type: Python Shell
Python version: Python 2 (1.0) [I'd created these jobs without a version and as per documentation, they should be defaulting to 0.9

The job fails to initialize with the following error:
No space left on device: 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pycparser

Has anyone else encountered the same error or have any potential resolutions?

Comment: Could you please share details about No. of DPUs, amount of data being processed and code snippet of what you are trying.

Comment: Increase dpu to 1 and check.